# Regularlyimport CSV flat files in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an API that reads data from an application and have the possibility to export that data to an excel file as a csv.

I know its possible to do a one time import of flat files in SQL Server Express but can i make it do this every week or so?

Comment: Excel files and CSVs are *completely* different beasts. An Excel file is a ZIP package containing XML data in a well documented format. You don't need either to import data into a database though, you could use SqlBulkCopy in your code to send the data to the server directly

Comment: In general there are a *lot* of options available to move data to SQL Server. You can use `bcp`, the BULK INSERT command, SSIS, or write your own program. You could even use a Powershell script to load data from a CSV file and write it to a table

Comment: Thanks guys, this gave me a lot to work with!